# Creating WordPress page using node.js

Tags: node.js, wordpress

I'm been trying it all day long, but only I can create Post, not Pages.
I modified the file `wordpress\lib\wordpress.js` and change `wp.newPost` for `wp.newPage` but title and content is empty and I'm sure it is incorrect.

I tried thousands times and ways but only I can get post type.

This is the code:

```
    var wordpress = require( "wordpress" );
    var client = wordpress.createClient({
    url: "http://MY-URL",
    username: "MYUSERNAME",
    password: "MAYPWD@200"
    });

client.newPost({
    postType: "page", 
        title: "Page from Node.js", 
        content: "This page was created sending remotely post from 
 Node.js.....",
            status: "publish",
                termNames: {
                        "category": ["Javascript", "Node"],
                        "post_tag": ["api", "js", "remote"]
                }
}, function( error, data ) {
    console.log( "Post sent! The server replied with the following:\n" );
    console.log( arguments );
    console.log("\n");
});



client.getPosts(function( error, posts ) {
    console.log( "Found " + posts.length + " posts!" );
});
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var wordpress = require("wordpress");
var client = wordpress.createClient({
    url: "http://MY-URL",
    username: "MYUSERNAME",
    password: "MAYPWD@200"
});

client.newPost({
    type: "page",
    title: "Page from Node.js",
    content: "This page was created sending remotely post from Node.js.....",
    status: "publish",
}, function (error, data) {
    console.log("Post sent! The server replied with the following:\n");
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log("\n");
});

client.getPosts(function (error, posts) {
    console.log("Found " + posts.length + " posts!");
});
```

No need to create `wp.newPage` as `wp.newPost` can be used to create posts and pages.

Please note:

- `postType: "page"` is incorrect, use `type: "page"` for page creation
- WordPress pages doesn't have category and tags, therefore, following code is unnecessary:

> ```
> termNames: {
>       "category": ["Javascript", "Node"],
>       "post_tag": ["api", "js", "remote"]
> }
> ```

Tested locally with:

- WordPress 4.9.8
- node-wordpress 1.4.1

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this way too but I did not remove termNames, so, I believe it was the problem. Great!. It is my first post here, so I don't know if I can do another related question or I must open a new thread.(I would like settled template; with PHP/plugin I used page_template="templatename.php").

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Post a new question for a new query.

Comment: @Cgonzalez No issue! You can participate here and increase your reputation that will unlock more privileges.